# que significa <ref *1> en listas enlazadas o [Circular *1]

Tags: javascript

estoy estudian programación y ahora empecé a ver listas enlazadas y empecé a probar que pasaba si hacia esto y/o aquello para ver las diferentes formas y en una de las curiosidades probé en hacer lo que esta en el código y salió <ref *1> y [Circular *1], no se si es algo grave o solo un pequeño error pero quería saber q significa

esto lo hice en RunJS.
`

```js
let loc = {
  gancho : null,
}
let carg = {
  carga : [1,2,3],
  gancho: null
}
let carg2 = {
  carga : 3,
  gancho: null
}
let carg3 = {
  carga : "hola",
  gancho: null
}
let carg4 = {
  carga : false,
  next : null
}

loc.gancho = carg

loc.gancho.gancho = carg

loc
```

`

Comment: también note que si ponía en loc.gancho = **carg2** en vez de **carg** se ejecutaba de forma "normal" ósea cambiaban la posición, pero no salía el <ref * 1> o [circular *1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69406446/13419694) de Stackoverflow inglés:

Ese **<ref*>** significa que hay una referencia circular. Es decir, dentro de un objeto hay una referencia a sí mismo.

En tu código sucede exactamente eso.

Primero asignas **carg** a la variable **gancho** de **loc**.

```
loc.gancho = carg
```

Seguidamente vuelves a asignar **carg** a la variable **gancho** de si mismo.

```
loc.gancho.gancho = carg
```

Puede que no sea tan obvio si aún no oíste hablar de valores y referencias.

---

Sucede que las variables actúan como un contenedor.

Cuando a una variable le asignas un tipo primitivo (números, cadenas de texto, `true`, `false`, `null`, `undefined` y unos pocos más) el valor *vive* en ella. Puedes consultarlos en la [especificación de ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-overview).

Cuando creas un objeto, este *vive* en alguna parte de tu memoria. Si asignas un objeto a una variable, la variable contiene una referencia a él pero no el objeto como tal.

Una referencia es una dirección de memoria. Entonces cuando tu quieres ver o modificar el objeto, el programa sabe dónde encontrarlo.

Notarás que la mayoría de los tipos en javascript, son en realidad objetos. Arreglos, funciones,

Links útiles:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/13419694
- https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0